# Perturbations of a Background Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory

I am reading some lecture notes on general relativity, where the author talks about perturbation theory applied to GR.  In the case of a weak gravitational field, one perturb about the Minkowski metric.

The author says that one can take small perturbations about a background spacetime apart from Minkowski, in which case the metric is

$g_{\mu \nu} = g_{\mu \nu}^{(0)} + h_{\mu \nu} $.

But in this case, what is the zeroth-order term $g_{\mu \nu}^{(0)}$, or does it depend on the exact metric, and then one just applies perturbation theory to it?  I assume there are some differences from traditional perturbation theory when applied to metrics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose a background metric around which you do the perturbation theory.  It could be Minkowski, for example, but it could also be Schwarzschild for another example.  The former might be appropriate if you are "far" from all strong sources.  The latter might be appropriate if you want to understand the relatively small deviations from Schwarzschild that you'd get if you had small objects orbiting a black hole.

As with other perturbation theory approaches, you need some insight into what makes a sensible background in order to get started.  In GR, that corresponds to picking the form of what you labeled $g_{\mu\nu}^{(0)}$ based on the physics of your problem.

Comment: So the zeroth-order term above could be the Schwarzchild metric, but depends on how you have formulated the problem as well as the physics of the problem?

Comment: No, if you want to perturb around the Schwarzschild metric then the zero-order term is the Schwarzschild metric. To have decided that you want to perturb around Schwarzschild, however, you should have had some insight into your system that suggests that the spacetime is "almost" Schwarzschild.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry if I was not clear.  The zeroth-order term is Schwarzchild, if the physical system can in some sense be regarded as close to Schwarzchild.  Is there some asymptotic sense in which any system can be regarded as Schwarzchild or Minkowski as one goes out to spatial infinity?

Comment: Yes, any localized distribution of matter with no angular momentum and no charge will look like Schwarzschild far enough away. (With angular momentum or charge then like the other "standard" BH solutions.) Schwarzschild itself looks like Minkowski even further away.

Comment: And if you add in angular momentum and charge, then it will resemble Kerr spacetime at a sufficient spatial distance?

Comment: Kerr for angular momentum and no charge. Reissner–Nordstrom with charge and no spin.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask, if you have a spacetime 4-manifold, what does that exactly mean for the geometry of the 4-manifold if it is equipped with a metric which is a small perturbation about another metric?  That the manifold is 'almost Schwarzchild' or isometric to Schwarzchild, what is the precise manifolds meaning?

Comment: @Tom You wouldn't use perturbation theory in the first place if you already knew that the new metric $=$ old metric $+$ extra factor, where the equality holds *exactly*, by definition. Most physical phenomena are not symmetrical, but they can often be approximated by perturbing around exact/symmetric solutions. That's why physicists use perturbation theory: for operational reasons, because they don't know the exact, full answer analytically (in many cases).

Answer (score 1):

As @Brick already said, $g_{\mu \nu}^{(0)}$ depends on the subject you want to apply perturbation theory to. 
It may be the Schwarzschild metric if you have small objects around a black hole.
Another example are gravitational waves, where you have the minkowski metric $\eta$ for flat space with a perturbation for the waves.

Comment: What does it imply for the spacetime 4-manifold if the metric with which it is equipped is a perturbation around some other metric, is there some asymptotic interpretation as one goes out to spatial infinity?

Comment: If i remember correctly, in the limit of an infinite distance the space time is always flat and therefore described by the minkowski metric.

Comment: But surely if the spacetime contains a black hole, it must be described by the Schwarzchild metric as one goes to spatial infinity?

Comment: The gravitation is described by the Schwarzschild metric.

$$
\mathrm{d} s^{2}=g_{\mu \nu} \mathrm{d} x^{\mu} \mathrm{d} x^{\nu}=-\left(1-\frac{r_{\mathrm{s}}}{r}\right) \mathrm{d} t^{2}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{r_{\mathrm{s}}}{r}} \mathrm{d} r^{2}+r^{2} \mathrm{d} \theta^{2}+r^{2} \sin ^{2}(\theta) \mathrm{d} \phi^{2}
$$

In the limit $r \rightarrow \infty$ you will get the minkowski metric

$$\text{d} s^2= -\text{d}t^2 + \text{d} r^2(\text{d}\theta^2 + \text{sin}^2 \text{d} \phi^2)$$